# Cardinalities in set coverings

Tags: sets, polynomial-time-reductions, backtracking

Let

- $I$ be a set of items;
- $C \subseteq \mathcal{P}(I)$ be a set of subsets of $I$, where $\mathcal{P}(I)$ stands for the power set of $I$; And
- $C(i) = \{ c \in C \mid i \in c \}$ be the set of sets, in $C$, containing item $i \in I$.

We state the following definitions.

**Definition 1**: We say that $\mathcal{C} \subseteq C$ *covers* item $i \in I$ iff. $C(i) \subseteq \mathcal{C}$, i.e. all sets containing item $i$ belong to $\mathcal{C}$.

For instance, let's consider the below example, where

- $I = \{1, \dots, 7 \}$;
- $C = \{a, b, c\}$;
- $a = \{1, 2, 4, 5\}$;
- $b = \{1, 2, 3, 6\}$; And
- $c = \{1, 3, 4, 7\}$.

[image: Short example]

In this case, the following *coverage* (cover/covered by) relations are present.

- Node 1 is covered by $\{a, b, c\}$;
- Node 2 is covered by $\{a, b, c\}$, and $\{a, b\}$;
- Node 3 is covered by $\{a, b, c\}$, and $\{b, c\}$;
- Node 4 is covered by $\{a, b, c\}$, and $\{a, c\}$;
- Node 5 is covered by $\{a, b, c\}, \{a, b\}, \{a, c\}$, and $\{a\}$;
- Node 6 is covered by $\{a, b, c\}, \{a, b\}, \{b, c\}$, and $\{b\}$; And
- Node 7 is covered by $\{a, b, c\}, \{a, c\}, \{b, c\}$, and $\{c\}$;

**Definition 2**: $\mathcal{C} \subseteq C$ is violated iff. $|\{ i \in I : C(i) \subseteq \mathcal{C} \}| > |\mathcal{C}|$, i.e. the number of items covered by $\mathcal{C}$ is greater than the cardinality of $\mathcal{C}$.

Still using the previous example, we have the following list of violated sets.

- $\{a, b\}$, since $|\{2, 5, 6\}| > |\{a, b\}|$;
- $\{a, c\}$, since $|\{4, 5, 7\}| > |\{a, c\}|$;
- $\{b, c\}$, since $|\{3, 6, 7\}| > |\{b, c\}|$; And
- $\{a, b, c\}$, since $|\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}| > |\{a, b, c\}|$.

My question is, how could we find all violated $\mathcal{C}$s? Obviously, we could simply enumerate $\mathcal{P}(C)$ and pick the proper subsets, however, I would like to know if the above problem could be translated to another problem or, even if there is a polynomial treatment for it.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Considering the bipartite graph $(I, C, (\in))$. The condition looks similar to [Hall's marriage condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem) but it is quite not the same.

Comment: @pcpthm thank you very much.